# Strange Results Synchronizing Player Positions over Network

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I am getting strange results when trying to sync player positions on the network.  I have a network game where I spawn two players into the world.  Each player has a network view with no observed object on it.  Each fixed update, I make an RPC call to update the position of the player on the server.  However, the position only begins to update when I move a player to the right.  Any other movement will not be shown, until I begin to move the player right, in which case the position will update immediately.  Here is the relevant code so far:

```
void FixedUpdate ()
{
    if (networkView.isMine)
    {
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
        anim.SetBool("ground", grounded);

        anim.SetFloat("vSpeed", rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

        float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        anim.SetFloat("speed", Mathf.Abs(move));

        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(move * MaxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);


        float speed = move * MaxSpeed;
        networkView.RPC("UpdateNetworkPosition", RPCMode.Others, LastPosition, speed);

    } 
}

[RPC]
void UpdateNetworkPosition(Vector3 newPosition, float speed)
{
    Debug.Log("Updating network position");
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPosition, Time.deltaTime * speed);
}
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the answer for this was rather simple.  I was passing the speed at which the character was moving into the RPC so that I could lerp the character by the correct speed to ensure that he would move correctly over the network.  However, since I used a speed determined by multiplying a speed factor by Input.GetAxis, anytime I moved left I was sending my RPC a negative speed value.  Therefore, it was trying to lerp from one position to another at a speed less than zero, and thus it would not move.  The problem was solved by using the absolute value for my speed factor by which to lerp.